# Flask Oauth2 google.authorize() callback missing 1 positional argument

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to authorize my Flask app with google, but google does not return the argument which I need to pass to callback function:

> TypeError: google_authorized() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'resp'

Here is a code:

```
@auth.route('/google-login')
def google_login():
    return google.authorize(callback=url_for('auth.google_authorized', _external=True))


@google.authorized_handler
@auth.route('/oauth2callback')
def google_authorized(resp):
    if resp is None:
        return f"Access denied: reason={request.args['error_reason']} error={request.args['error_description']}"

    session['google_oauth_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    userinfo = requests.get(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USERINFO_URL, params=dict(access_token=resp['access_token'],)).json()

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=userinfo['email']).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(userinfo['email'], '')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

    login_user(user)
    flash(f"Logged in as id={userinfo['id']} name={userinfo['name']}")
    return redirect(url_for('auth.home'))
```

How can I debug why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried setting a default value for the resp parameter? Maybe set it to None?

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere - yes, it next fails cuz of lack of `['error_reason']` in response. Google should definitely return something, but does not.